# Segue doesn't work when I call function from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, segue, appdelegate

I have a strange issue. I want to log in to my server from linkedin OAuth and I did it. All works successfully, but I cannot run segue programmatically.

This is my code in AppDelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    var username: String?
    var password: String?

    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let setViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LogInSocial") as! LogInSocialController

    var workingURL = url.absoluteString.componentsSeparatedByString("?")[1]
    workingURL.componentsSeparatedByString("&").map {
        $0.componentsSeparatedByString("=")
        }.reduce([:]) {
            (var dict: [String:String], p) in
            dict[p[0]] = p[1]

            username = dict["username"]
            password = dict["password"]

            return dict
    }

        setViewController.LNCredentials(url, username: username!, password: password!)
    }
```

So, when my app get response from linkedin webView it runs the function above. And inside of this function I placed this one

```
setViewController.LNCredentials(url, username: username!, password: password!)
```

This function is in my ViewController:

```
func LNCredentials(url: NSURL, username: String, password: String) {
    print("\(username) \(password)")
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("fromSocialToOpenChats", sender: nil)
}
```

Here I get in my logs `username` and `password`, but segue doesn't perform.

Who can help me with fixing this problem? I do not know why it doesn't work

Comment: Where have you instantiated "setViewController" ?

Comment: @iamyogish I've updated my question. It's inside of `sourceApplication`

Comment: what error you get? is there anything logged?

Comment: @Imran nope. There are no errors. All works perfectly in logs(it shows how the user logged in), just segue doesn't perform. The same screen stays

Comment: As you said your print("\(username) \(password)") gets called that means problem maybe in your storyboard segue .If possible post the screen shot of this segue in storyboard

Comment: @Imran no, there is not a problem with the segue, too. Because I have two options to sign in into my service(fb and linkedin). They are on the same Controller and have the same segue. When I log in from fb it works perfectly, but when I try to log in via linkedin nothing happens

Comment: try adding it in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {self.performSegueWithIdentifier("fromSocialToOpenChats", sender: self) })

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade did it work ?